# Referencing HTML in multiple locations?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery tabs and I have a bunch of dropdowns that are populated by queries. The thing is the exact same dropdowns (with identical options) are on different tabs/dialogs (basically they are being used more than once). I was wondering if there is a way around copy/pasting the same select/options outputted html in every place they are used. Is there a way I can reference them? This way my loaded page isn’t 5,000 lines long. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: This would even make more sense if you had posted relevant code

Comment: Just imagine a dropdown with 10,000 options that is being used multiple times on the same page.

Comment: Use a templating language to suppress the size of the client's download. Rendered HTML will probably be around the same size.

Comment: "Just imagine a dropdown with 10,000 options" it would be a awful dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript can clone a node and append it wherever you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var my_nav_containers = ["nav1", "nav2", "nav3"];

    for(var i = 0; i < my_nav_containers.lengt; i++) {
        var cloned_nav_menu = $("#seed_nav_menu").clone(true);
        $(cloned_nav_menu).attr("id", (my_nav_containers[i] + "_cloned_menu"));
        $("#". my_nav_containers[i]).append(cloned_nav_menu);
    }
})
```

Comment: All your cloned_nav_menu will have the same ID, bad idea

Comment: When dealing with so many select/options would cloning... impact the browser's speed?

Comment: @Travis - Possibly, it would depend on the user's machine. If the delay is slight, you can implement something to let the user know they need to wait, which helps the user experience.  If its too long, you can build the HTML via some server side language, but then they have to pull all that data over their connection (as 11684 alluded to in the OP comments).  Its a tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file extension of the page to .php and use the `include()` function to pull in the menu code from another file that only has the menu code in it.

So basically, take all the dropdown menu code you want to replicate, remove it from the main file and put it in its own file (like `dropdown.php`).  Then, anywhere in the main page code that you want to pull this code in, all you have to add is `<?php include('dropdown.php'); ?>` and you're good to go!